# image is save in server but cannot be accessed laravel

Tags: laravel, server, file-manager

I am using laravel file-manager to store image and it was working fine in http but after changing to https the image are not being displayed although they are being stored in public folder. Only image that are added recently have that problem old image are fine.

Comment: Is there an error in your console?

Comment: No errors in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in storage:link so after unlinking and then linking that it worked.